# How do I inject a header line into a pipe via a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, netcat, socat

I am working on a process to send data via a pipe from one server to another for processing.

Although this is not the exact command, it might look something like this:

```
tail -f logfile | grep "abc" | grep "def" | grep -v "ghi" | netcat -q 0 n.n.n.n 7777
```

I would like to wrap all those greps into a script and more importantly prepend the pipe to `netcat` with an identifier, so the command would look like this:

```
tail -f logfile | myscript.sh {id}
```

The script listening on the other end should receive:

```
{id}
[Line 1 of the logfile]
[Line 2 of the logfile]
...
```

Wrapping it in a script is easy:

```
#!/bin/sh
id=$1
grep "abc" | grep "def" | grep -v "ghi" | netcat -q 0 n.n.n.n 7777
```

but I cannot figure out how to inject `$id` at the start.

The receiving end is using

```
 socat -u tcp-l:7777,fork system:/dev/receivePipe
```

so if there is a different way I could get the id (for example somehow as a parameter to `/dev/receivePipe`), or via an environment variable, that would work too.

EDIT: The final answer was figured out in the comments of the accepted answer:

```
#!/bin/sh
{
  printf '%s\n' $1
  grep "abc" | grep "def" | grep -v "ghi" 
} | netcat -q 0 192.168.56.105 7777
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
{
  printf '%s\n' "${1-default-id}"
  awk '/abc/ && /def/ && ! /ghi/'
} | socat - tcp:n.n.n.n:7777
```

`${1-default-id}` expands to the first positional parameter if specified or `default-id` otherwise. Replace with `${1?}` to exit with an error if not passed any argument instead (or `${1?The error message}` to specify an error message instead of the default).

We redirect the output of a command group that runs `printf` to output the ID and the filtering commands (here with your `grep` pipeline replaced with a single `awk` invocation that does the same thing a bit less clumsily) to `socat`/`netcat`.

Or to only print the ID if and when one line has been read and matches:

```
#! /bin/sh -
ID=${1-default-id} awk '
  /abc/ && /def/ && ! /ghi/ {
    if (!already_printed++) print ENVIRON["ID"]
    print
  }' | socat - tcp:n.n.n.n:7777
```

Or to prepend the ID (and a space character) to every line:

```
#! /bin/sh -
ID=${1-default-id} awk '
  /abc/ && /def/ && ! /ghi/ {
    print ENVIRON["ID"], $0
  }' | socat - tcp:n.n.n.n:7777
```

Beware `awk`, like `grep` will buffer their output when it goes to a pipe (to anything other than a tty device). With the GNU implementation of `awk` (aka `gawk`), you can add a call to `fflush()` after each `print` to force the flushing of that buffer. See also the `-Winteractive` of `mawk`. In most `awk` implementations, doing a `system("")` would also force a flush. The GNU implementation of `grep` has a `--line-buffered` option to force a flush after each line of output.

Also note that `tail -f logfile` is short for `tail -n 10 -f logfile`. Chances are you actually want either `tail -n +1 -f logfile` for the whole log file to be processed, and then `tail` carrying on `f`ollowing the file, or `tail -n 0 -f logfile` to process only the lines being added *from now on*.

Comment: I am a little confused as to why you are piping to `socat`. Did you mean to pipe to `netcat`, or is something else going on? Regardless, I don't want to convert the pipes to other things such as `awk`. The `grep`s were just an example for this post. In reality, it might be other intermediary programs that it's getting piped through, with no `greps` at all. All I want to do is inject a line at the start of what ends up going to `netcat`.

Comment: @BenHolness, seeing that you already used `socat`, I replaced your `netcat` call with the `socat` equivalent. In any case, the first approach will allow you to insert the header before any command.

Comment: I used `netcat` on the sending server as `socat` is not installed there. I'm trying to understand how to use the first approach without awk and with the other pipes. I tried removing the `awk` line entirely (didn't work) and taking out all of the `/abc/` parts in the `awk` line (also didn't work). Here's an example of what I tried (the one without `awk`), with different, perhaps non-sensical, intermediary programs (and squashed because multi-line comments aren't possible):

`#!/bin/sh
{
  printf '%s\n' $1
} | grep "abc" | head -n 10 | netcat -q 0 192.168.56.105 7777`

Comment: @BenHolness, replace the `awk '/abc/ && /def/ && ! /ghi/'` (which is the same as `grep abc | grep def | grep -v ghi`) with your filtering command (like `grep abc | head` or `grep -m10 abc`)

Comment: Got it, with (for example): `#!/bin/sh
{
  printf '%s\n' $1
  grep "e" | head -n 3
  } | netcat -q 0 192.168.56.105 7777`

Thanks!